# Calculate average of an array with objects that has different (number of) and name of attributes

Tags: arrays, object, average

I am a beginner and not very good with object handling, but I am more of old school looping. That being said I studied object handling because looping became very troublesome with objects, but now I am stuck. I also checked some similar subjects on this forum, but that didn't help me very much.

I am trying to loop through an array of objects that can have a different number of attributes and attribute names can be different, accept for attribute time, and calculate the group average of a given number of object(attributes):

```
data[
  {time: 1674054188078,
  val_1: 7,
  val_2: 8,
  val_3: 9,
  val_n: 10
  },
  {time: 1674053988079,
  val_1: 9,
  val_2: 2,
  val_3: 3,
  val_n: 10
  },
  {time: 1674054188080,
  val_1: 4,
  val_2: 3,
  val_3: 2,
  val_n: 6
  },
  {time: 1674054188081,
  val_1: 9,
  val_2: 8,
  val_3: 7,
  val_n: 1
  },
  {time: 1674054188082,
  val_1: 7,
  val_2: 8,
  val_3: 9
  val_n: 10
  },
  {time: 1674054188083,
  val_1: 7,
  val_2: 8,
  val_3: 9
  val_n: 10
  }
//etc.....
]
```

This is what I got so far. But no solution to average calculation.

```
// Calculate average of points within the chosen interval
// data is original array
// s_table is new array with calculated averages
groupby = 3;  // Is the number of objects(attributes) to get mean value of
const arrObjects = Object.keys(data[0]) ?? [];
arrObjects.splice(arrObjects.indexOf("time"), 1);
let s_table = [];
arrObjects.forEach((element, index) => {
  s_table[index] = [];
  data.forEach(obj => {

    //some sort of loop with average calculation with "groupby"

    s_table[index].push({ time: obj.time, ???: (obj[element]), etc.... })

  })
})
node.warn(s_table);
```

What I expect is follow results:

```
groupby = 2;
s_table[
  {time: 1674054188078,
  val_1: 8,
  val_2: 5,
  val_3: 6,
  val_n: 10
  },
  {time: 1674054188080,
  val_1: 6.5,
  val_2: 5.5,
  val_3: 4.5,
  val_n: 3.5
  },
  {time: 1674054188082,
  val_1: 7,
  val_2: 8,
  val_3: 9
  val_n: 10
  },
//etc.....
]
```

```
groupby = 3;
s_table[
  {time: 1674054188078,
  val_1: 6.66,
  val_2: 4.33,
  val_3: 4.66,
  val_n: 8.66
  },
  {time: 1674054188081,
  val_1: 7.66,
  val_2: 8,
  val_3: 8.33,
  val_n: 7
  },
//etc.....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach using `reduce` over the the `data` array and returning an array containing objects where each property is the average value of the that same property across the whole group. The group size is given by `groupBy`.

The function modeled here `reduceAverage({entries, groupBy})` uses the most functional approach on iterations and embeds in distinct callback functions its atomic operations to better deliver their semantics.

It also takes into account the chance that the last "group" might be smaller than the given `groupBy` and in that case it will calculate the average based on the size of that latest group.

In case the group size requested is smaller then the passed array size, it will throw an error.

```js
const data = [
  {time: 1674054188078,val_1: 7,val_2: 8,val_3: 9,val_n: 10},
  {time: 1674053988079,val_1: 9,val_2: 2,val_3: 3,val_n: 10},
  {time: 1674054188080,val_1: 4,val_2: 3,val_3: 2,val_n: 6},
  {time: 1674054188081,val_1: 9,val_2: 8,val_3: 7,val_n: 1},
  {time: 1674054188082,val_1: 7,val_2: 8,val_3: 9,val_n: 10},
  {time: 1674054188083,val_1: 7,val_2: 8,val_3: 9,val_n: 10}
];

const o = reduceAverage({entries: data, groupBy:2});
console.log(o);

function reduceAverage({entries, groupBy}){
  
  if(entries.length < groupBy)
    throw new Error('groupBy should be less than entries.length');
  
  //returns the properties of obj except time
  const getProps = (obj)=>{
    return Object.entries(obj).filter( ([key]) => key !== "time" );
  }
  
  //resets each property value in group as the average based on groupBy
  const setAverage = (group, groupBy)=>{
    getProps(group).forEach( ([key, value]) => group[key] = value / groupBy );
  };

  //sums all the property values from orig object to dest object
  const sumPropertyValues = ({orig, dest})=>{
    getProps(orig).forEach( ([key, value]) =>{
      if(!(key in dest)) dest[key] = 0;
      dest[key] += value;
    });
  };
  
  //returns latest group pushing a new one in groups if needed
  const feedLatestGroup = ({groups, groupBy, i, entry})=>{
    //latest group
    let group = groups[groups.length-1];
    //if current entry index belongs to next group
    if (i % groupBy == 0){
      //sets the average of the previous group object, before..
      if (groups.length > 0) setAverage(group, groupBy);
      //..creating and pushing the next group with the current time
      group = {time: entry.time};
      groups.push(group);
    }
    return group;
  }

  //creates the reduction of the passed data array
  const reduction = entries.reduce(
    //for each entry
    (groups, entry, i) => {
      //feeds and return the current group
      const group =
        feedLatestGroup({groups: groups, groupBy: groupBy, i: i, entry: entry});
      //sums the property values of current entry into current group
      sumPropertyValues({orig: entry, dest: group});
      //returns the accumulator
      return groups;
    },
    //groups initalized as empty array
    []
  );
  
  //calculates the average of the last object using the correct count
  const reminder = entries.length % groupBy;
  const count = (reminder == 0) ? groupBy : reminder;
  setAverage(reduction[reduction.length-1], count);
  
  return reduction;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort, Diego D. This routine is almost halfway there, I think. I don't exactly understand yet how it works, but in the given example of 6 objects in the array and groupby = 3 means there are 2 groups in the output array, everything goes well. But if groupby = 2, that means there are 3 groups in the output array, then the average values of the third group are always wrong, they are even sort of random. Maybe also you can explain how the group value is determined?

Comment: Maybe you can explain how following statement works:     const count = (remainder == 0) ? 3 : remainder;

Comment: @Henkkas that was the terrible mistake. For some strange reason I used a static value in that moment fitting my scenario and forgot to use the correct expression: the `groupBy` variable. That part is meant to calculate the average of the latest group since it could contain less items compared to the groupBy (if count % groupBy > 1). That's what `count` is expected to be, the number of items for the latest group so to use as denominator in the average function.

Comment: of course i corrected the code that now works in the demo. By the way the functional approach may be hard to grasp but it's just a matter of factoring down the atomic operations that process and return lists and chain them all together.

Comment: @Diego_D Now it runs perfectly, as far as I can see. I tried different variations of the input array, and always correct output. Thanks very much, you where very helpfull to me, and besides that I learn a lot on how to construct something like that. Also thanks for explaining more what is happening in the functions you designed.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. please take the time to accept the answer if it correctly addressed the question.